# How to split following String to number-letter units

Tags: java

What pattern would I use to split the following types of strings.:
"NumStringNumString..."

For example "3X12Y5Z" into a String array of "3X","12Y", and "5Z"

Note: if necessary assume that the string is only one character as the original problem stated. I would still prefer the more general solution though.

I thought that the pattern "^(\d+\w+)" would work, but it doesn't cut it.

Comment: Remove `^` from your regex

Answer (score 3):

`^` forces to the beginning of the string, where you want to find all the patterns.

> if necessary assume that the string is only one character

I'll also assume uppercase characters only

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+[A-Z]")
  Matcher m = p.matcher("3X12Y5Z")

  while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group())
  }
```